# Stripe SEPA payment method

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to implement stripe subscriptions in php. I create my subscriptions on the checkout session which payment method is Card and everything works fine. However, I want to check if going one step further is possible. I want to keep the first payment method as Card upon creating the subscription but I want all the succeeding payments to have SEPA payment method. Is that possible? And if yes could you please give me general steps for the overall process?

Comment: Why don't you keep it simple first. Can you create a single payment with SEPA?

Comment: If you are looking for the latest solution for Stripe SEPA payment, check out --> https://techtolia.com/Stripe/New/ and https://techtolia.com/Stripe/New/Subscriptions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start your subscription with the initial card payment.

Separately, you should follow Steps 1-4 of the [guide for setting up Sepa Debit subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/sepa-debit).

Then, at Step 5, you can either set the Customer `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method)) or you can set the `default_payment_method` ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-default_payment_method)) on the Subscription, depending on how you choose to set things up. This will replace the payment method to be used for future renewal payments on the Subscription.

Comment: Thank You so much !

Comment: I would like to ask you where do you suggest  to put the form that includes the account number and the email .. should it be on the success page that comes after completing the first payment ?

Comment: -@Nolan Can you please take a look at this question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66983230/9409877